# Solovay's paper from AD+ that all sets are Ramsey

Tags: forcing, set-theory, reference-request

For my research I've been trying to locate Solovay's proof that AD+ implies that all sets are Ramsey (or completely Ramsey, depending on the terminology).  I know that it uses Mathias forcing but I can't locate the paper.  Does anyone know where I could find it or another paper that reproduces his proof using that technique?

Answer (score 10):

About all you need is in Adrian's paper "[Happy families](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=491197)". It is not spelled out as following from ${\sf AD}^+$, of course, since the concept did not exist yet.

Anyway, if you are familiar with Solovay's arguments in his [paper](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=265151) on all sets of reals being measurable (or as discussed in the Feng-Magidor-Woodin [paper](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1233821) on universally Baire sets), then all you want to read is section 2 (up to 2.2.3) of my [paper](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2777751) with Richard Ketchersid, "A trichotomy theorem in natural models of ${\sf AD}^+$", in Set Theory and Its Applications, Contemporary Mathematics, vol. 533, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 2011, pp. 227-258, MR2777751, and also available at my papers [page](http://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/papers).

Very briefly, what we use of ${\sf AD}^+$ is little more than all sets of reals having $\infty$-Borel codes. If $S$ is an $\infty$-Borel code for a set of reals $A$, then $L[S]$ is a model of choice, so (from determinacy), its reals are countable and in fact $\omega_1^V$ is inaccessible in $L[S]$. One can now run the argument that sets of reals are Ramsey in the Solovay model, noting that there are (in $V$) generics over $L[S]$ for Mathias's forcing, and the proof is concluded from the defining property of $\infty$-Borel sets.

Since the proof uses the $\infty$-Borel machinery so explicitly, it is still open whether ${\sf AD}$ suffices for this result.

Comment: (Thanks, Martin, for fixing the typo.) 

Comment: So, what is the reference? I'm trying to write the bibliography for my dissertation and am desperately searching for the exact reference.

Comment: OK, maybe I was not explicit enough: There is *no* Solovay paper with the result you ask for. The references I gave and the accompanying sketch are as explicit as it gets in the published literature.